# `find -exec` in git alias

Tags: git, find, alias

This alias in `.git/config`:

```
pycat = !find -iname '*.py' -exec cat {} \;
```

Gives me this in the shell:

```
$ git pycat
fatal: bad config file line 19 in .git/config
```

I've tried quotes, no quotes, switching quote types, escaping everything up to four levels, but I can't figure out what's making git unhappy here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little farting around says it's the semicolon,

```
pycat = !find -iname '*.py' -exec cat {} "\\;"
pycat = !find -iname '*.py' -exec cat {} "';'"
pycat = "!find -iname '*.py' -exec cat {} \\;"
pycat = "!find -iname '*.py' -exec cat {} \";\""
```

all work. Semicolons are old-school comment-to-eol syntax, that may be what's going on here. So the config parser's eating one layer of doublequotes.

(edit: [yup](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html#_syntax). It even says so in the doc:

> The syntax is fairly flexible and permissive; whitespaces are mostly ignored. The # and ; characters begin comments to the end of line, blank lines are ignored.

)

Comment: I could swear I tried that third one, but I guess not, because it does indeed work. Thanks!