# After a git pull from a colleague's work a lot of files that I did not edit become conflicted

Tags: git

We are two people working on a git repository. Almost every time my colleague pushes stuff to the repository, when I pull them in my local repo, a lot of files that I have never touched (or even opened for that matter) become conflicted.

Can anyone suggest a way to investigate it?

Comment: maybe everytime he's using this, git add src/ , I'm not sure , but I think I had this problem once

Comment: Are you both working on the `master` branch? Do you have other branches? Has either of you rebased or amended changes that have been pushed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Check the exact nature of the diff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27439837/6309): it might involve [eol (end of line)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) style (`\n\r` vs `\n`)

```
git diff --word-diff-regex=.
```

In that case, make sure your:

- `git config --global core.autocrlf` is set to false
- your editor respect eol style and don't attempt to change it.

Comment: I am using MacOs and my core.autocrlf is set to input while my colleague is using Windows and has his core.autocrlf set to true (as is the [suggestion of git-scm](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#Formatting-and-Whitespace)). We have two different suggestions it seems :)

Comment: @bmenekl always set core.autocrlf to false. Everywhere. For everybody.

Comment: @bmenekl see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/2354278/6309 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/17628353/6309

Comment: @bmenekl in some cases you might have to edit the .gitattributes file also http://stackoverflow.com/a/15161420

Answer (score 1):

One way to try fixing this problem is for both of you to `clone` the repo to a different local folder, and then committing in a test change each. If you both push and pull and it is OK, it may be that one of you tried to rewrite history by `rebase`ing or `amend`ing pushed commit(s).

If those test commits work, you can commit and push any pending changes each of you have, and point your editor to the new repo. I tend to recommend *not* deleting your old one for a few days, in case there is a change you forget to copy!