# .gitattributes control commited end of line symbols

Tags: git, newline

I use GIT. I want to disallow eol conversion for text file. For example, if someone in my project has the file with CRLF and someone else has the file with LF, I want all of the checkin and checkout the files with those corresponding end line symbols. I read about .gitattributes, but I didn't understand it completely, since as far as I understood it only able to mark some files as text and other ones as binary. Also there is -text property, which is "text not set" however I don't get if this is the same as binary. Note that I want to have my merges to work correctly for both types of files - with CRLF and LF too.

Comment: First, make sure that `git config core.autocrlf` returns false.

Comment: @VonC well, I use .gitattributes because I don't want to configure it manually on every machine.

Answer (score 1):

See [Git line endings after normalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24577629/git-line-endings-after-normalization)

TL;DR
Just create a .gitattributes file in the root of your repo with the two lines:

```
* -text
* whitespace=cr-at-eol
```

This will turn off all line ending normalization by Git and leave it up to you to manage.